# 方(かた) suffix pitch accent

Tags: suffixes, pitch-accent

When 方 is used as a suffix like these for example:
考え方、作り方、言い方、喋り方、etc.

is there a way to guess/know the reading or is it just straight up random?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this [paper](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/onseikenkyu/26/1/26_1/_pdf) titled 接尾辞「-方」を含む派生名詞でのアクセント変異 ―平板化率にみる地域差と母方言からの干渉―.

It says, by citing an earlier study, that, as a general rule, the accent of `[V ます-stem]-方` is determined by the accent of the verb. If the verb is *heiban*, it is also *heiban* (〜[かた]【HH】), and otherwise, it is either *nakadaka* with the pitch falling after か (〜[かた]【HL】) or *odaka* (〜[かた　]【HHL】). However, many deviations from this rule, in both directions, are observed, and as the authors have found out through their research, speakers from Kansai have a significantly stronger tendency to flatten those that are expected to be either *nakadaka* or *odaka* (when they attempt to speak in standard Japanese) compared to speakers from other regions.

I checked [NHK日本語発音アクセント辞典](https://sakura-paris.org/dict/NHK%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E7%99%BA%E9%9F%B3%E3%82%A2%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E8%BE%9E%E5%85%B8/suffix/%E6%96%B9) here (which is known to be not the latest) and found the following words. I marked deviations with (*) and also added remarks following (**) where needed.

- [ある]【HL】 → [ありかた　]【LHHHL】, [ありかた]【LHHL】
- 言う [いう]【LH】 → [いいかた]【LHHH】
- 生きる [いきる]【LHL】 → [いきかた　]【LHHHL】, [いきかた]【LHHL】
- 行く [いく]【LH】 → [いきかた]【LHHH】
- 致す [いたす]【LHH】, [いたす]【LHL】 → [いたしかた]【LHHHH】 (** this should be seen as a separate word, rather than as 致す方法)
- 入れる [いれる]【LHH】 → [いれかた]【LHHH】
- 植える [うえる]【LHH】 → [うえかた]【LHHH】
- 歌う [うたう]【LHH】 → [うたいかた]【LHHHH】
- 売る [うる]【LH】 → [うりかた]【LHHH】
- 売れる [うれる]【LHH】 → [うれかた]【LHHH】
- 選ぶ [えらぶ]【LHL】 → (*) [えらびかた]【LHHHH】 (** only this pattern is listed)
- 押す [おす]【LH】 → [おしかた]【LHHH】
- 折る [おる]【HL】 → [おりかた　]【LHHHL】, [おりかた]【LHHL】
- 織る [おる]【HL】 → [おりかた　]【LHHHL】, [おりかた]【LHHL】, (*) [おりかた]【LHHH】
- 買う [かう]【LH】 → [かいかた]【LHHH】
- 飼う [かう]【HL】 → [かいかた　]【LHHLL】 (** [かいかた　]【LHHHL】 is not listed)
- 書く [かく]【HL】 → [かきかた　]【LHHHL】, [かきかた]【LHHL】
- 考える [かんがえる]【LHHHL】, [かんがえる]【LHHLL】 → [かんがえかた]【LHHHHL】 (** [かんがえかた　]【LHHHHHL】 is not listed)
- 聞く [きく]【LH】 → [ききかた]【LHHH】
- 切る [きる]【HL】 → [きりかた　]【LHHHL】, [きりかた]【LHHL】
- 組む [くむ]【HL】 → [くみかた　]【LHHHL】, [くみかた]【LHHL】
- 死ぬ [しぬ]【LH】 → [しにかた]【LHHH】
- 立つ／裁つ [たつ]【HL】 → [たちかた　]【LHHHL】, [たちかた]【LHHL】 (** [たちかた]【LHHH】 is also listed but only for 立ち方 as kabuki jargon, which refers to a person, not a method)
- 食べる [たべる]【LHL】 → [たべかた　]【LHHHL】, [たべかた]【LHHL】
- 使う [つかう]【LHH】 → [つかいかた]【LHHHH】
- 作る／造る [つくる]【LHL】 → [つくりかた　]【LHHHHL】, [つくりかた]【LHHHL】
- 綴る [つづる]【LHL】, [つづる]【LHH】 → [つづりかた　]【LHHHHL】, [つづりかた]【LHHHL】 (** [つづりかた]【LHHHH】 is not listed)
- 解く [とく]【HL】 → [ときかた　]【LHHHL】, [ときかた]【LHHL】
- 取る／捕る [とる]【HL】 → [とりかた　]【LHHHL】, [とりかた]【LHHL】
- 並ぶ [ならぶ]【LHH】 → [ならびかた]【LHHHH】
- 縫う [ぬう]【HL】 → [ぬいかた　]【LHHHL】, [ぬいかた]【LHHL】
- 話す [はなす]【LHL】 → [はなしかた　]【LHHHHL】, [はなしかた]【LHHHL】, (*) [はなしかた]【LHHHH】
- 振る [ふる]【LH】 → [ふりかた]【LHHH】
- 見る [みる]【HL】 → [みかた　]【LHHL】, [みかた]【LHL】
- [やる]【LH】 → [やりかた]【LHHH】
- 揺れる [ゆれる]【LHH】 → [ゆれかた]【LHHH】
- 読む [よむ]【HL】 → [よみかた　]【LHHHL】, [よみかた]【LHHL】

They mostly follow the rule with one notable exception in 選び方. Listing [おりかた]【LHHH】 for 織り方 and not for 折り方 seems arbitrary. Personally, the *odaka* pattern sounds weird in my head for all of them, and as a Kansai-ben speaker myself, I find *heiban* acceptable for some of those for which it is not listed.

Comment: Amazing answer!

Comment: thank you bro i couldn't find anything anywhere 